# Algorithm to find number of possible string variations

Tags: string, algorithm

For a password related project, I'm looking for an algorithm that calculates the number of possible variations a certain string can have based on a few options. For now the string variation options are upper/lowercase and character to number replacements (like *E=3*)

For example, lets take the string **'abc@def'**

With just upper/lower variations, there are 6 characters that can vary, and the total number of possible variations is **2^6 = 64**.

With just character to number replacements, there are 2 characters that qualify *(A=4,E=3)*. That makes the number of variations **2^2 = 4**.

I'm struggeling with calculating the number of variations when both methods are enabled.
I've tried (2^6 * 2^4), but obviously this doesn't consider the overlap that occurs when applying both.

For example, the variations **'abc@def'** and **'abc@dEf'** both result in **'abc@d3f'** with number substitution on de character **E** and should be counted as one.

Somehow I can't figure this out :)

Comment: In case of `abc@def` `a` can be turned into `0..9` or `A`, right? So we have `11` options for a single *letter* and `11**6 == 1771561` variations for the password provided.

Comment: No, `a` can only be turned into `4` or `A`. The number substitution is done  like 'l33t'

Comment: In this case we have **3** options for `a` and `e`; **2** options for `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and only **1** option for `@`. Finally we have `3 * 2 * 2 * 1 *  2 * 3 * 2 = 144` variants

Comment: If there are a_1, a_2, ... alternatives for letter 1, 2, ..., then the number of combinations is the product a_1 * a_2 * ... * a_n.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko apparently I was thinking way too difficult; this is what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count all possibilities for *each letter* within the password and *multiply* them together:

```
  letter options count
     a    a A 4      3
     b      b B      2 
     c      c C      2
     @        @      1 
     d      d D      2
     e    e E 3      3
     f      f F      2
```

Finally we have `3 * 2 * 2 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 2 == 144` variants